# How to ignore the new line in table value?

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

I am trying to export a SQL Server table to CSV file. What I am doing is call the sqlcmd command

```
C:\>sqlcmd -S EC2AMAZ-5UNBD90 -Q "SELECT * FROM dbo.PMDOCS  WHERE hmy=95613900;" -s "," -o "C:\pmdocs_ms_v1.csv" -E -y0
```

A particular column in this table could contains 'new line' character, such as this record, what they write to the CSV file is like:

```
95613900,25,1731323,2020-06-06 11:59:04.000,\\asp1\kfs\kusersdefpaths\Pangea Properties\Live\Attachments\WorkOrder\06-2020\5883_1179695_0.jpg,Tier 547 door is broken
Tier 543 does not lock latch broken 5883_1179695_0.jpg,0,0,0,6889803,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,0
```

A single record was stored in two lines. Please advise what should I do to make them in one line.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Presumably you want to remove the new line character with something like `replace` or `translate`

Comment: SQL Server has crappy support for CSV output. Sure, you can generate comma delimited data, but it doesn't have logic to quote or escape special cases as is required (or customary) for CSV. Ideally, any value that contains commas, newlines, or quotes should be wrapped up as a double quoted string, with any embedded strings quoted. Optionally, all values could be quoted this way using `QUOTENAME()`.  So instead of `SELECT * from ...` you could `SELECT QUOTENAME(ColA, '"') AS ColA, QUOTENAME(ColB, '"') AS ColB, ...`.

Comment: Other alternatives are to eliminate the troublesome characters using `REPLACE()` or seek out a package that includes good built-in CSV support so that you don't have to reinvent the wheel. This might be a C# application with appropriate libraries. Powershell might also have the ability to capture the SQL output and write to a CSV file without mangling the data.  This all assumes that the receiving system properly interprets quoted values when reading the data back in. Try a google search for ["powershell sql server to csv"](https://www.google.com/search?q=powershell+sql+server+to+csv).

Comment: @TN SQL Server does support CSV's quite well (now). `sqlcmd` and `bcp` however, have bad support. Though them OP's data should probably be quite identified so that they can use `BULK INSERT` to read the data more easily.

Comment: For reference, see [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180#section-2), section 2, numbered items 5 through 7. This is an informational paper, and not all applications follow the conventions described therein.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned `sqlcmd` and `bcp` have poor/non-existent support for well-formed CSV.

Instead, install the DbaTools in Powershell

```
Import-Module dbatools;
```

And simply use [`Invoke-DbaQuery`](https://docs.dbatools.io/Invoke-DbaQuery.html)

```
Invoke-DbaQuery `
  -SqlInstance 'EC2AMAZ-5UNBD90' `
  -Query 'SELECT * FROM dbo.PMDOCS WHERE hmy=95613900;' `
  -As DataTable `
| Export-Csv -Path 'C:\pmdocs_ms_v1.csv' -NoTypeInformation;
```

You can pass parameters using the `-SqlParameter` parameter.